# Teukolsky (Bardeen-Press) equation ingoing coordinates

Tags: black-holes, gravitational-waves, perturbation-theory

EDIT: I can't seem to delete this question, so I've posted the solution below (I must have made an algebra error-someone checking all this would still be appreciated!). I've left the question as is.

The Bardeen-Press (i.e. Teukolsky equation for a Schwarzschild black hole) in Schwarzschild coordinates reads:

\begin{equation}
\frac{r^4}{r^2-2Mr}\partial_t^2\psi
-2s\left(\frac{Mr^2}{r^2-2Mr}-r\right)\partial_t\psi
-\left(r^2-2Mr\right)^{-s}\partial_r\left(\left(r^2-2Mr\right)^{s+1}\partial_r\psi\right)
+(l-s)(l+s+1)\psi
=
0
\end{equation}

This equation is not regular at the horizon (r=2M). I want to transform this equation to horizon penetrating (more specifically, ingoing Eddington-Finkelstein) coordinates. I apply

\begin{equation}
v=t+r+2M\mathrm{log}\left(r-2M\right)
,
\end{equation}

use the chain rule, and get an equation of the form

\begin{equation}
-2r^2\partial_v\partial_r\psi
+\frac{2r\left(\left(s-3\right)M+\left(2+s\right)r\right)}{2M-r}\partial_v\psi
+\frac{q(r)}{(2M-r)r}\psi
+\cdots
=
0
,
\end{equation}

where $q(r)$ is a long function and $\cdots$ contains terms regular in $r-2M$. I have read sources that seem to suggest that if I perform the field redefinition

\begin{equation}
\psi\equiv r^{-1}\left(r^2-2Mr\right)^{-s}\Psi
,
\end{equation}

and rewrite everything in terms of $\Psi$ the equation becomes regular at the horizon (still at $r=2M$). I have tried this and for the life of me I cannot seem to get a regular equation at the horizon. When I plug in the above transformation I get

\begin{equation}
-2r^2\partial_v\partial_r\Psi
-\frac{2r\left(\left(1-3s\right)M+\left(s-1\right)r\right)}{2M-r}\partial_v\Psi
+\cdots
=
0
,
\end{equation}

the coefficient for $\partial_v\Psi$ is still singular! I feel like I may be making a algebraic error but I cannot find where the problem is.

I am looking for a reference or an explicit calculation that the above manipulations lead to a wave equation regular on the black hole horizon.

Comment: This is discussed in section V of https://arxiv.org/pdf/gr-qc/9907085.pdf, but they don't go into much detail for the manipulations. (It does seem that the $r^{-1}$ shouldn't be there in your field redefinition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I must have made an algebraic error-the answer I believe is:

I use the coordinate
\begin{equation}
v\equiv t+2M \mathrm{ln}\left(r-2M\right)
,
\end{equation}
and

\begin{equation}
\psi\equiv \left(r^2-2Mr\right)^{-s}r^{-1}\Psi
,
\end{equation}

and the Bardeen-Press (Teukolsky) equation is then both horizon penetrating and regular on the horizon:

\begin{equation}
r\left(r+2M\right)\partial_v^2\Psi
-4Mr\partial_v\partial_r\Psi
-r\left(r-2M\right)\partial_r^2\Psi
+2\left(sr+\left(1+s\right)M\right)\partial_v\Psi
+2\left(sr-\left(1+s\right)M\right)\partial_r\Psi
+\left(\left(l-s\right)\left(l+s+1\right)+\frac{2(1+s)M}{r}\right)\Psi
=
0
.
\end{equation}